# Delete Excel columns that "don't" contain certain text, or copy only cells that do

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

The situation:

- I have hundreds of excel files (`.xls` and `.xlsx`);
- each of these files contains multiple sheets;
- each of these sheets has multiple columns of information (in this case, contact details).
- However, none of the files (or even any of the sheets within any of the files) are formatted the same (e.g. sometimes email addresses might be in column J, sometimes in column A, or D, etc; sometimes it will be labelled "email", sometimes it will be labelled "Email Address", sometimes it will have no label at all).

**I need to get the email addresses from all of the sheets in all of the files into one, single text file.**

I am planning on either

1. deleting all of the columns that don't contain email addresses (i.e. everything that doesn't contain the "@"), then converting each sheet within each file to a csv/txt file.
2. or copying each cell that contains the "@" from each sheet of each file and paste it into one csv/txt file.

How on earth would I go about doing this? Either of these solutions? Anyone?

(NB: all of the excel files are located in the same folder)

Many thanks!

Comment: How about converting each .xls/.xlsx file into a csv first, then just use AWK or Notepad++ to replace/delete with regular expressions?

Comment: Converting xls/xlsx to csv would involve opening each xls/xlsx file and saving each sheet as it's own csv. This will be very time consuming. I am trying to eliminate this time (there are hundreds of files, encompassing thousands of sheets).

Comment: How prevalent are the email adresses? 1% of the used space, 50% etc - as this will go to the coding method. And any reason why vbscript over vba?

Comment: well, ok, but you should rather not expect an out-of-the-box solutions to this. 

You need to get examples on how to open,close and parse files with vba and how to do this troughout folder structures. I would say, the easiest way to get your data, should be to search for the column with the @ in each sheet, then copy that column-values to an array or maybe even copy them directly to a text-stream of your destination CSV/txt-File.

You should consider some marking/tracking of files, which were processed already too.

Comment: I would say the email addresses represent between 20%-40% of the total data. And I guess VBscript over VBA... no reason at all! Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach that is probably 90% of what you need (in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) as it was easier to test!)

In short:

1. The code uses `Dir` to open every *xls** file under `strDir` = "c:\temp\"
2. The true last cell is found in each sheet of that workbook to set the working range
3. The code loops through each row of that range, and filters an 1D array of that column for "@'
4. The filtered strings are then written to a [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) file

and so on

*[Updates: The code now]*

*- loops through rows not columns which avoids the size issue, and the output now matches the input files by rows*
 *- prefixes the email list dump with the workbook and worksheet name*

**code**

```
Sub GetEm()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim strFile As String
Dim strEmail As String
Dim strDir As String
Dim strFiltered As String
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objTF As Object

With Application
    lngcalc = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

strDir = "c:\tmp\"
strFile = Dir(strDir & "*.xls*")
Set objTF = objFSO.createtextfile(strDir & "output.csv", 2)

Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strDir & strFile, False)
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        Set rng1 = ws.Cells.Find("*", ws.[a1], xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
         'avoid blank sheets
        If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
            Set rng2 = ws.Cells.Find("*", ws.[a1], xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
            Set rng2 = ws.Range(ws.[a1], ws.Cells(rng1.Row, rng2.Column))
            'avoid array errors on sheets with data only in A1
            If rng2.Columns.Count = 1 Then Set rng2 = rng2.Resize(rng2.Rows.Count, 2)
            For Each rng3 In rng2.Rows
            strFiltered = Join(Filter(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rng3)), "@"), ",")
                If Len(strFiltered) > 0 Then
                objTF.writeline (wb.Name & "," & ws.Name & ",") & strFiltered
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    wb.Close False
    strFile = Dir
Loop

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strDir & "output.csv", False)
wb.Sheets(1).Columns.AutoFit

With Application
    .Calculation = lngcalc
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: that is brilliant! A fantastic solution. I actually managed to work around the 16,000 limit be simply outputting the result to .txt. rather than .csv.A fantastic solution, thank you very much indeed.

Comment: Thx :) The updated code now works on rows not columns which fixes the size issue, plus the `csv` output pre-appends the workbook name and worksheet name to each email record